# C Implementation of atof

Tags: performance, beginner, c, reinventing-the-wheel, homework

I'm a beginner at C. 
I'm currently implementing atof to build a raytracer, however I'm still learning how to efficiently write programs.

## Assignement

### Instructions

The program takes a scene description file as argument to generate objects. Some of these paramaters are float. Example of the file.

[image: Scene Description file]

I'm parsing through the file. As I'm restricted in terms of lines allowed per function and I'm currently learning how double pointers work, I'm using a double char pointer. Example of one such function using `lc_atof`.

```c
int    a_parsing(char *str, t_pars *data)
{
    if (*(str++) == 'A')
    {
        if (((data->a_ratio = lc_atof(&str)) >= 0.0) && data->a_ratio <= 1.0 && errno == 0)
        // 
            if (((data->a_R = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_R <= 255 && errno == 0)
                if (*(str++) = ',' && ((data->a_G = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_G <= 255 && errno == 0)
                    if (*(str++) = ',' && ((data->a_B = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_B <= 255 && errno == 0)
                        return (skip_space(&str));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

### Current code to review:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>

static float    conversion(char **str)
{
    double    d_nbr;
    double    power;

    d_nbr = 0.0;
    power = 10.0;
    while (isdigit(**str))
    {
        d_nbr = d_nbr * 10.0 + (**str - 48);
        if (d_nbr > FLT_MAX)
        {
            errno = EIO;
            return (-1);
        }
        (*str)++;
    }
    if (**str == '.')
    {
      (*str)++;
      if (isdigit(**str))
      {
        d_nbr = d_nbr * 10.0 + (**str - 48);
        if (d_nbr > FLT_MAX)
        {
            errno = EIO;
            return (-1);
        }
        (*str)++;
        return ((float)(d_nbr / power));
      }
    }
    errno = EIO;
    return (-1);
}

float            lc_atof(char **str)
{
    float    n;
    int        sign;

    n = 0.0;
    sign = 1.0;
    if (!str || !*str)
    {
        errno = EIO;
        return (-1);
    }
    while (isspace(**str))
        (*str)++;
    if (**str == '+' || **str == '-')
    {
        if (**str == '-')
            sign = -1.0;    
        (*str)++;
    }
    if (!isdigit(**str))
    {
        errno = EIO;
        return (-1);
    }
    if ((n = conversion(str)) == 0 && errno != 0)
       return (-1);
    return (sign * n);
}
```

The only tweaks to the actual atof I've made is having a double char pointer as argument and returning -1 in case of errors.

Every input much appreciated.

Comment: You only process a single digit after the dot. Is it intended?

Comment: @vnp Yes it is.

Comment: Related: [\`atof\` implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/119986)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you're writing your own scanner, instead of using the facilities already provided by e.g. scanf, or doing the scanner in (f)lex?

Comment: @jamesqf One of the side goals of my assignement is to learn how library functions work by retyping them.

Comment: @lcols19: Writing your own implementations is good practice, of course, but I would not be surprised if atof or the scanf functions weren't actually implemented as finite state machines, such as would be generated by flex, since they're often much more efficient than straightforward coding.  I haven't looked at the source, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Portability

There is no guarantee that this code will be using ASCII so it would be better to use `'0'` rather than `48` which is something of a magic number. Using `'0'` makes it more readable and easier to understand.

### `lc_atof` Doesn't Handle String Termination or End Of Line Correctly

This code doesn't handle a NULL terminated string or an end of line character. The function `isspace()` returns `true` for end of line so the code will walk right past it.

```
    while (isspace(**str))
        (*str)++;
    if (**str == '+' || **str == '-')
    {
        if (**str == '-')
            sign = -1.0;
        (*str)++;
    }
    if (!isdigit(**str))
    {
        errno = EIO;
        return (-1);
    }
```

### Complexity

I reaize that you didn't ask for this to be review, but the complexity of each `if` statement in the example call function is too much and caused me to make an error in my review previously:

```
int a_parsing(char* str, t_pars* data)
{
    if (*(str++) == 'A')
    {
        if (((data->a_ratio = lc_atof(&str)) >= 0.0) && data->a_ratio <= 1.0 && errno == 0)
            // 
            if (((data->a_R = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_R <= 255 && errno == 0)
                if (*(str++) = ',' && ((data->a_G = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_G <= 255 && errno == 0)
                    if (*(str++) = ',' && ((data->a_B = lc_atoi(&str)) >= 0) && data->a_B <= 255 && errno == 0)
                        return (skip_space(&str));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I would rewrite the code as :

```
#define MAX_COLOR   0xFF
int a_parsing_prime(char* str, t_pars* data)
{
    if (*(str++) == 'A')
    {
        data->a_ratio = lc_atof(&str);
        if (!errno && data->a_R <= MAX_COLOR)
        {
            if (*(str++) = ',')
            {
                data->a_G = lc_atoi(&str);
                if (!errno && data->a_G <= MAX_COLOR)
                {
                    if (*(str++) = ',')
                    {
                        data->a_B = lc_atoi(&str);
                        if (!errno && data->a_B <= MAX_COLOR)
                        {
                            return (skip_space(&str));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

which truely shows the complexity of the function.

Comment: NULL is a pointer constant.  Perhaps you meant ASCII NUL (`'\0'`) as the string terminator?  IMO it's clearer to just say 0-terminated.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm don't think it's any less clear, or rarely used; I see null-terminated everywhere in the context of strings/ string_views: https://www.bing.com/search?q=null-terminated+site:cppreference.com&form=APMCS1&PC=APMC

Comment: Why adopt this style instead of early returns? Something like this: https://pastebin.com/997kVR4Q? The function stops looking so complex and is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's really a question for the OP and not for me. I kept their logic intact as much as I could.

Comment: I'm limited in terms of number of lines (25) a function is allowed to have. `a_parsing` is actually the shortest function I have. I understand it is not easy to read and will split it into several functions.

Comment: @anki: Ok, "clearer" isn't the real reason.  Being technically accurate without having to use the obscure term "NUL" is the reason.  The fact that "null-terminated" is widely mis-used for strings (rather than pointer-based data structures like linked lists) doesn't mean you should, too.  (Unlike natural language which does evolve new meanings and usage, technical language should be kept pure for maximum clarity.)

Answer (score 10):

- Choosing `EIO` for error reporting is very dubious. `lc_atof` doesn't do any input or output; why should it report IO error? If the return type cannot represent the result (e.g. `d_nbr > FLT_MAX`), a logical choice is `ERANGE` or `EOVERFLOW`. If the conversion cannot complete because of the malformed argument (e.g. `!isdigit(**str)`), the logical choice would perhaps be `EINVAL`.

  That said, I do not endorse setting `errno` in the library function. A long standing tradition is to set `errno` in system calls only. I know that this tradition is more and more violated these days, but still. If you have other means of error reporting, stick with them.
- Using inout parameter (`str` in your case) is not advisable. It unnecessarily complicates the code, both on the caller side and the callee side. The callee is forced to use extra indirection too many times, and to worry about parenthesizing `(**str)++`. In turn, the caller loses track on where the parsable began (say, it needs to log the malformed number). Look how `strtof` handles this:

  ```
    float strtof(const char *restrict nptr, char **restrict endptr);
  ```

  Here `nptr` is an in-only, and `endptr` is out-only.
- I am surprised that you decided to limit the utility of the function by handling only one digit after the decimal dot. It is not a big effort to handle all of them, and the benefits are much greater.
- There is no need to parenthesize the return value. `return` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: *It is not a big effort to handle all of them* That's an overstatement, unless you just mean naive best-effort without actually getting the nearest `float` for every decimal string input.  Real-world `atof` implementations typically use big-integer extended precision to handle integer and fractional parts.  e.g. the MUSL libc implementation https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/floatscan.c?id=v1.1.20#n66 is ([according to the author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391330/create-a-precise-atof-implementation-in-c#comment91728246_52391330)) pretty dense but self-contained.

Comment: Eric Postpischil has an answer on an (unfortunately deleted) SO question with discussion and example code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301315/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-ieee-754-string-to-float-rounding/51304463#51304463  Needs some more votes to undelete the question.  It points out the potential difficulties with integer overflow of the integer part, and that you potentially need all the decimal digits for rounding decisions.

Comment: Whole articles have been written on accurately implementing `strtod`, such as https://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/ about David Gay's widely-used implementation, vs. GLIBC's pure-integer version https://www.exploringbinary.com/how-glibc-strtod-works/